# Supporting multiple screens in Android for numerous activities and resources

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution

I have around 10 activities in an app and around more than hundred images. Now need to provide support for multiple screens of diff sizes and densities. If I need to create for small,large and xlarge sizes even though it will be customization of 30 more activities rest aside diff densities for a specific size :O Is there any way I can stretch the whole layout depending on the size and densities, I mean what is the best way to solve this problem. It must be a very common problem but I am missing something here. I read the android dev. screen support doc but still confused. Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give an answer specific to your project, but in general Android does a good job of this all by itself. All layouts will automatically scale if you haven't specified fixed dimensions (ie using px instead of dp). When it comes to fullscreen images (background and the like) it is best if you provide several resolutions (in the drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi etc) folders. You may also have to look at the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for an ImageViews you may have.

Read through the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on how to support multiple screen resolutions. It provides all the information you need and it goes into detail on how to provide different layouts not only for different screen resolutions, but also for different screen orientations and things like smallest width etc (for tablet specific layouts)

Comment: I have used dp for sure, but for some of the screens layouts become unorganized

Comment: Well, as I said, it's hard to give specific advice without seeing some code and/or XML. Please edit your question and add XML for a specific activity and tell us what's wrong with it.